How to discard property being written from json converter?
Requrement.
For json serialization with json.net:

Convert invalid double values (e.g. double.NaN) to null.
Make double shorter (G3).
Do not write properties with null values.

Sounds simple?
The obvious solution.
The first and second is done by making json converter, right?
The third is done by using JsonSerializerSettings with NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, correct?
Well, there is a problem, they don't work together. If value is null, then converter is not even called, good. But if converter produces null, the null-value-ignoring doesn't happens..
Attempt.
Below is the code or try repro directly. What should I do?

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new A(
            d: 1.23456789,
            nd1: 1.23456789,
            nd2: null,
            nd3: double.NaN,
            da: [1.23456789],
            nda: [1.23456789, null, double.NaN]);

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            Converters = { new MyJsonConverter() }
        });

        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }


public class MyJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(double) || objectType == typeof(double?);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is double input && double.IsFinite(input))
            writer.WriteRawValue(input.ToString("G3", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
        else
            writer.WriteNull();
    }

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public record A(
    double d,
    double? nd1,
    double? nd2,
    double? nd3,
    double[] da,
    double?[] nda)
{ }


Output:

{"d":1.23,"nd1":1.23,"nd3":null,"da":[1.23],"nda":[1.23,null,null]}

Expected output is without nd3:

{"d":1.23,"nd1":1.23,"da":[1.23],"nda":[1.23,null,null]}

P.S.: I couldn't think of a good title, thefore asking how to solve my attempted solution (XY problem). I think such title describes intent the best and someone may face similar issue, where value produced by converter should influence the json property.

Check the serialization attributes documentation

@Cleptus, what is your idea? Which attribute and where to apply?

No need to create a custom converter. I was suggesting both JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn) and JsonProperty attributes as per the example in the documentation I linked.

Also for the two decimal formatting you could use a custom converter for that properties. Some time ago I answered a similar question with datetime conversion

@Cleptus, do you propose to completely exclude property from serialization even if it contains a valid non-null value? That's not my wish. In second comment you say I need converter, how those two comments combine together?

Didn't notice the "Do not write properties with null values" requirement. My first comment would only work if always the same property has the null value (guess that is not the case). The second comment is a quick and easy way to formatting a property (G3 or other format)
